# При работе программы происходит зацикливание

Tags: python, pyqt5

Друзья, продолжаю изучение и делаю детскую простую программу. Но столкнулся с ошибкой и не могу ее обойти. Загружается картинка и ребенок должен выбрать один из четырех вариантов ответа, если не правильно появляется QMessageBox с ошибкой, когда правильно открывается новая функция с новой картинкой и новыми вариантами ответа. Но при работе на второй картинке появляется какое то зацикливание QMessageBox, даже на правильном варианте сначала вылетает QMessageBox и только потом срабатывает функция. Такое чувство что прошлые функции продолжают работать и не закрыты или даже не знаю. Надеюсь на помощь.

```
def zagcifr(self):
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(26)
    self.ButtonStart.hide()
    self.ButtonVar1.setText("3")
    self.ButtonVar1.setFont(font)
    self.ButtonVar2.setText("1")
    self.ButtonVar2.setFont(font)
    self.ButtonVar3.setText("2")
    self.ButtonVar3.setFont(font)
    self.Button4.setText("4")
    self.Button4.setFont(font)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 491, 251))
    self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Risunki/resized_grib-bely.jpg"))
    self.ButtonVar1.clicked.connect(self.kar1)
    self.ButtonVar2.clicked.connect(self.kar1)
    self.ButtonVar3.clicked.connect(self.kar1)
    self.Button4.clicked.connect(self.kar1)

def kar1(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    a = int(sender.text())
    if a == 1:
        self.var2()
    else:
        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setText("УПС. Не Верно")
        msgBox.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                              QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
        msgBox.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('PathToIcon/icon.png'))
        msgBox.exec_()

def var2(self):
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(26)
    self.ButtonStart.hide()
    self.ButtonVar1.setText("1")
    self.ButtonVar1.setFont(font)
    self.ButtonVar2.setText("3")
    self.ButtonVar2.setFont(font)
    self.ButtonVar3.setText("2")
    self.ButtonVar3.setFont(font)
    self.Button4.setText("4")
    self.Button4.setFont(font)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 80, 491, 251))
    self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Risunki/klubnika2.jpg"))
    self.ButtonVar1.clicked.connect(self.kar2)
    self.ButtonVar2.clicked.connect(self.kar2)
    self.ButtonVar3.clicked.connect(self.kar2)
    self.Button4.clicked.connect(self.kar2)

def kar2(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    b = int(sender.text())
    if b == 2:
        self.var3()
    else:
        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setText("УПС. Не Верно")
        msgBox.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                              QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint)
        msgBox.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('PathToIcon/icon.png'))
        msgBox.exec_()
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример, который может продемонстрировать вашу проблему.

Comment: Убрал Вариант 3, но боюсь что это и есть минимум чтоб понять что делает и откуда берет, остальное я вырезал. Если кратко то при нажатии на любую кнопку else с msgBox срабатывают раньше чем проверка основного условия, но происходит это начиная с функции kar2 и чем дальше тем больше вылетает msgBox

Comment: Самодостаточный пример означает, что его хотя бы можно запустить. Как минимум вы подписываетесь на событие клика `self.ButtonVar1.clicked.connect( )` и эта подписка сохраняется. Потом вы просто навешиваете на него все больше и больше обработчиков, которые работают одновременно. Никто же не запрещает иметь много обработчиков на одной кнопке. Удаляйте предыдущие и может проблема уйдет: `self.ButtonVar1.clicked.disconnect( )`.

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то что надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем проблема вам уже ответили. А еще у вас много дублирующего кода.
А минимально-полный пример может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Dialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ButtonStart = QPushButton("ButtonStart")
        self.ButtonVar1  = QPushButton()
        self.ButtonVar2  = QPushButton()
        self.ButtonVar3  = QPushButton()
        self.Button4     = QPushButton()
        self.label       = QLabel()

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 5, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.ButtonStart,0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.ButtonVar1, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.ButtonVar2, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.ButtonVar3, 3, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.Button4,    4, 1)

        self.zagcifr()

    def zagcifr(self):
        self.ButtonVar1.setText("3")
        self.ButtonVar2.setText("1")
        self.ButtonVar3.setText("2")
        self.Button4.setText   ("4")
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 491, 251))
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png"))

        self.ButtonVar1.clicked.connect(self.kar1)
        self.ButtonVar2.clicked.connect(self.kar1)
        self.ButtonVar3.clicked.connect(self.kar1)
        self.Button4.clicked.connect   (self.kar1)

    def kar1(self):
        if self.sender().text() == '1':
            self.var2()
        else:
            self.msgError()

    def var2(self):
        self.ButtonVar1.setText("1")
        self.ButtonVar2.setText("3")
        self.ButtonVar3.setText("2")
        self.Button4.setText   ("4")
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 80, 491, 251))
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"))

        self.disConnect()                                      # <--------

        self.ButtonVar1.clicked.connect(self.kar2)
        self.ButtonVar2.clicked.connect(self.kar2)
        self.ButtonVar3.clicked.connect(self.kar2)
        self.Button4.clicked.connect(self.kar2)

    def kar2(self):
        if self.sender().text() == '2':
            self.var3()
        else:
            self.msgError()

    def var3(self):
        self.ButtonVar1.setText("5")
        self.ButtonVar2.setText("2")
        self.ButtonVar3.setText("8")
        self.Button4.setText("3")
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 491, 251))
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("avatar.jpg"))
        self.disConnect()                                      # <--------
        self.ButtonVar1.clicked.connect(self.kar3)
        self.ButtonVar2.clicked.connect(self.kar3)
        self.ButtonVar3.clicked.connect(self.kar3)
        self.Button4.clicked.connect(self.kar3)

    def kar3(self):
        if self.sender().text() == '3':
            self.var4()
        else:
            self.msgError()

    def var4(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Финиш", "Спасибо за участие в игре!")
        self.close()        

    def msgError(self):
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", "УПС. Не Верно")

    def disConnect(self):                                      # <--------
        self.ButtonVar1.clicked.disconnect()
        self.ButtonVar2.clicked.disconnect()
        self.ButtonVar3.clicked.disconnect()
        self.Button4.clicked.disconnect()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton {
            background: gray;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 26px
        }
    """)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]